# redraw the whole client area

Tags: c#, wndproc

Since a little bit i tried to add a grip to a window to resize it. I follow an example and it works fine for resizing. But my window does paint properly, it seems like it does not clear before redrawing or does not redraw the whole client area.

Here is my code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
      case (int)WinApi.Messages.WM_NCHITTEST:
                WinApi.HitTest ht = HitTestNCA(m.HWnd, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                if (ht != WinApi.HitTest.HTCLIENT)
                {
                    // ht == HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)ht;
                    return;
                }
                break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

the result is here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl95Z.png)

Comment: Normally this is handled for you, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Try adding an `OnLoad()` overload to the control, and inside it set `this.ResizeRedraw = true;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson thank you, now it's better but still there is a flash when redrawing, is there anyway to make it smoothly.

Comment: Try also setting `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` or call `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`

Comment: Now it resize perfectly. thanks again @MatthewWatson.